# What's difference between Summation and Concatenation at neural network like CNN?

Tags: tensorflow, deep-learning, conv-neural-network

What's difference between summation and concatenation at neural network like CNNs?

For example Googlenet's Inception module used concatenation, Resnet's Residual learning used summation.

Please teach me.

Comment: I'm afraid that you are looking for a book or an article, not an answer on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 2):

Concatenation means to concatenate two blobs, so after the concat we have a bigger blob that contains the previous blobs in a continuous memory. For example:
blob1:

```
1
2
3
```

blob2:

```
4
5
6
```

blob_res:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
```

Summation means element-wise summation, blob1 and blob2 must have the exact same shape, and the resultant blob has the same shape with the elements a1+b1, a2+b2, ai+bi, ... an+bn.
For the example above,
blob_res:

```
(1+4) 5
(2+5) 7
(3+6) 9
```